# How do you use (or can you use) the Linq Intersect method on a child list member of an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-3.0

I am doing the following...

```
//first I have a list of sports...
List<string> sports = new List<string> {"football","basketball"}

//then I have a list of partners who are offering that sport
List<Partner> = Partner.GetAvailablePartners();

//Partner is a type that has a List<string> Sports members.
```

Now what I want to do is filter my list of Partners so that only partners who are offering the sports contained in `sports` but I can't figure out how.

I thought could use the Intersection extension method like this...

```
var filteredPartners = (List<Partner>) (from p in partners where p.Sports.Intersect(sports).Count()>0 select p);
```

but I it doesn't work I guess because I am acting on a member list not the root list.

Can this be done with the intersect (or some other linq) method?

Seth

Comment: _Why not?_ What error do you get?

Comment: This does compile and run. But on the above line I am getting InvalidCastException..."Unable to cast object of type 'WhereListIterator`1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need the results in a List then call ToList() at the end of your LINQ statement. Otherwise, you should be able to do:

```
IEnumerable<Partner> partners = partners.Where(p => p.Sports.Intersect(sports).Count() == sports.Count);
```

...or in a resultant List:

```
List<Partner> partners = partners.Where(p => p.Sports.Intersect(sports).Count() == sports.Count).ToList();
```

Comment: This did it.  I cast my list of partners to IEnumerable<Partner> and then the Intersect clause worked fine.  I am surprised that that was needed sense List implements IEnumerable.  Since Intersect extends IEnumerable it but (apparently) not List why did the compiler not give an error.  And how come other extension methods work just fine on a list?

Comment: @SethSpearman: **All** extension methods work fine on `List<T>`.  However, none of them (except `ToList()`) _return_ `List<T>`.  You didn't get a compiler error because you explicitly told the compiler not to give an error by using a cast.

Answer (score 0):

`.Where()` and all other lINQ methods return an `IEnumerable<T>` with lazy iteration, not `List<T>`.
You can't cast them to `List<T>`.

If you want a `List<T>`, call `ToList()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use intersect.

Example using two IEnumerables

```
var ids = original.Select(x => x.ID).Intersect(yourEnumerable);
```